# Worker threads in ExpressJS routes, any gotchas?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, worker

I've recently experimented with `Worker Threads` in Node and was pleasantly surprised how great they worked.

I've built an Express app that does complicated computational work on one of the POST routes. Are there any gotchas when using `Worker Threads` in a the request cycle scenario?

I've read that spawning too many threads will actually have negative performance effects. If that route starts to experience more traffic, that means more threads and ultimately worse performance? What are some of the things to watch out for in this scenario?

Comment: If you're legitimately concerned about spawning too many threads, then instead of spawning a certain number of threads every time the route is used, you can have a fixed pool of threads and a work queue for them.